# Securing third party library controller in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an asp.net core 3.1 project and I created an authorize attribute which works just fine.
I am also using a third party library which exposes some HTTP endpoints and they seem to work fine. The only problem is that they are publicly open as this is a third part library and I cannot modify the code to add `Authorize` attribute.
Is there any other way to secure these 3rd party Http endpoints? I tried to check the below code if I can specify it in the routes section but I see no option

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
 {
     endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
 });
```

Anyone knows how to secure them?

Comment: Please show code that mapping third party library endpoints

Comment: There isn't any code that maps them. I just reference the library and its endpoints are exposed without doing any extra configuration

Comment: If library, that you using does not providing some points to change behaviour, there is no possibility to do what you want. You must to dig in your third party library documentation to find out some useful points to insert your code.

Comment: There isn't any way to add authorization from Startup.cs based on the route?

Comment: Only if your third library provides such functionality. As a tip, try to find something like `RequireAuthorization` in documentation, this is default method that enables authorization for specific routing ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.authorizationendpointconventionbuilderextensions.requireauthorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1))